# How to get error message from Node server to client?

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I have a route that POSTs a new "post" resource. In this route, I'm using the AWS SDK to put an item in DynamoDB. In the event that this operation with the AWS API encounters an error, I want to propagate the error message from the server to the client. However, when I attempt to do this I just get an error message that reads "Error Error: [object Response]".

Here's the route.

```
router.post('/', authMiddleware, async (req, resp) => {
    let reqBody = req.body;
    let imagePath;
    if (reqBody.imageUrl) {
        imagePath = reqBody.imageUrl;
    } else {
        let path = req.file.path;
        console.log(path);
        imagePath = path.substring(path.indexOf('/'), path.length);
        console.log(imagePath);
    }

    let newPost = {
        'id': uniqid(),
        'title': reqBody.title,
        'description': reqBody.description,
        'date': new Date(),
        'text': reqBody.text,
        'country': reqBody.country,
        'imageUrl': imagePath
    };
    let params = {
        TableName: table,
        Item: newPost
    };
    console.log("Adding a new item...");
    console.log(params)


    docClient.put(params, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.error("Unable to add item. Error JSON:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
            resp.status(400);
            resp.send(err.message);
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("Added item:", JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            resp.sendStatus(200);
            return;
        }
    })
})
```

And here's the POST request from the client (create-posts.js)

```
fetch('/posts', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
}).then((response) => {
    console.log(response.text()); // line 23
    console.log(response.statusText); // line 24
    console.log(response.status); // line 25
    if(response.status === 400) {
        console.log('Received 400.'); // line 27
        throw new Error(response);
    }
    return response.text();
}).then((data) => window.history.go()
).catch((err) => alert(`Error ${err}`));
```

When I make this POST request, I see the following in the console:

```
[Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) (posts, line 0)
[Log] Promise {status: "pending"} (create-post.js, line 23)
[Log] Bad Request (create-post.js, line 24)
[Log] 400 (create-post.js, line 25)
[Log] Received 400. (create-post.js, line 27)
```

And finally, I also get an alert message that reads "Error Error: [object Response]".

However, if I look at the server-side logs, I see a useful error message:

```
"Unable to add item. Error JSON: {
  "message": "One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string"}
```

What I want to do is pass this error message from the server to the client. Can anyone help a Javascript/Node/Express noob figure this out?

Comment: Try simply logging err without JSON.stringify and post it here.

Comment: If I log error without JSON.stringify, my server-side logs just have the raw JSON: message: 'One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string'

Comment: Your express route is: `/`
Your fetch POST request has the url `/posts`
Is this your intention?

Try: 

`router.post('/posts', authMiddleware, async (req, resp) =>`